# Use Scala (or java) method in Gradle build script

Tags: java, scala, gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle build script which has to call a Scala (or Java) method in a Task.

currently, i have src/.../utils/lib.java

this file has a simple class with a static method that I would like to call in the build.gradle script.

but I have no idea how to import this file and use this method.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how your gradle script is set up and what you are trying to accomplish. Without seeing it, it is hard to give a concrete all encompassing response. Here are the two most common methods I know of that would allow you to execute code in a gradle script.

1) To directly answer your response, to execute a static java method, it needs to be compiled first. If the rest of your build requires this to be executed, then you would need to structure this as a multi-project build.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Assuming you have

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

You would then be able to create a jar with the class containing your static method, and create a task that you can execute of type `Exec` or `JavaExec` that would execute this jar.

2) The easier and less complex approach:

Since gradle allows you to directly execute groovy code, if possible, I would try to move the logic from the static method into the gradle file. You can reference Objects and methods on the *org.gradle.api* to customize a lot of build actions.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/

Here is an example from my build.gradle use to copy resources files after a compile step into the build directory before it is packaged into a jar.

```
compileJava {
    doLast {
        def f = file("src/main/java/resources/db/migration")
        println "Copying SQL from {$f} to {$buildDir/db/migration}"
        copy {
            from file(f)
            into file("$buildDir/db/migration")
            include('*.sql')
        }

    }
}
```

This may not be the easy solution that you were looking for but I hope it gives you some good guidance.